# Combs and Perms

Tags: combinatorics

11 letters are selected with replacement from the word ‘BRACED’.
i) How many different combinations of letters are possible?
ii) How many distinguishable permutations of ‘ABRACADABRA’ are there?

I do not understand how 11 letters are selected, with replacement, from a 6-letter word. However, here's m'y attempt:

i)

Permutations of the letters of BRACED: 6! = 720

or

$6^{11}$ if an 11-letter word is created using the 6 letters = 362 797 056

ii) 11! / (5! * 2! * 2!) = 83 160

What's wrong with my answers?

Comment: Are they wrong?

Comment: Can we again replace the replaced letter?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not understand how 11 letters are selected, with replacement, from a 6-letter word.

Well, you take one letter, make a copy of it, and put it back where it was.

Since there are $6$ different letters, there are $6^{11}$ different ways to repeat this process $11$ times.

---

> How many distinguishable permutations of ‘ABRACADABRA’ are there?

We have $5A+2B+1C+1D+2R$, hence $\dfrac{(5+2+1+1+2)!}{5!\cdot2!\cdot1!\cdot1!\cdot2!}$ distinguishable permutations.